# Is there an optimal setup for campfires?

Tags: terraria

So apparently, a campfire, which requires 20 wood and 5 torches, can increase hit point regeneration when "close" to it.

I'm wondering if there is an optimal setup for these campfires.  It seems that if I stand too close to it, there is little-to-no hit point regeneration, with about the same speed as normal hit point regeneration.

Is there an optimal setup for campfires? If I place multiple campfires, can I increase the healing rate?

Comment: I thought this too and tried it (in an unscientific manner) and did not detect any real benefit at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effects of campfires do not stack - that is even if you have 500 campfires around you, you will still only heal at the rate of one. As for your problem regarding being too close for it, it is probably just a glitch.

It is important to note that a campfire is not even close to being as effective as a regen potion. Though every bit helps, campfires alone does not increase regeneration fast enough when you're facing off against any reasonably difficult enemies.  For this reason, if there are only 1 or 2 players, stick to regen potions. If there are 3 or more, a campfire will be a better use of resources.

Comment: Does the increased rate from regen potions and campfire stack?

Comment: @Zibbobz Yes it will stack

Comment: But as you said: Every bit helps. That is why I place a campfire in all of my arenas or in general places where I am planning to fight for a longer time. Same thing for the heart lantern, when grinding items I usually have a campfire, a heart lantern and in really annoying cases even honey with me.